# It is possible sum values by keys? how do it (php)

Tags: php

Array for example

```
$array = array(
  array('first'=>5), array('first'=>4), array('second'=>3)
);
```

How sum values by keys for result:

```
$result = array(
  'first'=>9,
  'second'=>3
);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can iterate array $array and do whatever you want. And you can do it with any language if you have some pprogramming skills.

```
$result=array();
foreach ($array as $sub) {
  foreach ($sub as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($result[$key])) $result[$key] += $value;
    else $result[$key]=$value;
  }
}
```

Note: if you getting this info from database, it is better to sum it using database resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk_recursive`:

```
$results = array();
array_walk_recursive($array, function($number, $key){
    global $results;
    if (! isset($results[$key])) $results[$key] = 0;
    $results[$key] += $number;
});
```

This works in php >= 5.3